# Regular expression condition

Tags: asp.net

My textbox should allow "The first character should be alphabetic or numbers and the remaining characters only numbers"

```
ex: #999999999 here # represent alphabet(a-z,A-Z) or numbers(0-9),
```

Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you need something like this:

- in case you need 0 or more numbers after first symbol
  `[a-zA-Z0-9][0-9]*`
- in case you need 1 or more numbers after first symbol
  `[a-zA-Z0-9][0-9]+`